# Django Queryset on JSONField with nested data, whereby a dictionary key has a hyphen in the key name

Tags: python, django

I have a jsonfield called "data" that contains the following for one row, and I'm experimenting with querysets:

```
{
  "id": "5cfbffb4-c03a-4905-aa3c-8ecd878f56d7",
  "owner": "string",
  "name": "some string",
  "short-name": "some string",
  "description": "some description",
  "sub-identifier": [{
    "sub_id": "d2610379-abcc-4201-ad89-5f3ad3a4b1c2",
    "sub_name": "Test Dummy1",
    "sub-short-name": "some further name",
    "sub_description": "some description"
  }, {
    "sub_id": "7461b531-a181-483d-a554-ab8761c1d672",
    "sub_name": "Test Dummy2",
    "sub-short-name": "some further name",
    "sub_description": "some description"
  }]
}
```

So I can create a new query set

```
queryset = TestModel.objects.filter(data__name='some string')
```

this returns my queryset result correctly.  However, I've noticed that if the dictionary key has a hyphen in it then it gives me an error. The following returns a syntax error:

```
queryset = TestModel.objects.filter(data__sub-identifier__sub_id__0='d2610379-abcc-4201-ad89-5f3ad3a4b1c2')
```

SyntaxError: expression cannot contain assignment, perhaps you meant "=="?

Is there a way to tell Django to accept key names that may have a hyphen in?  Or do I have to ensure that in my json data that all keys use underscores instead?

Also, can I loop through each element in the list within sub-identifier to test the sub_id for a number I'm looking for.  Naturally, I can do this as above using the 0, but hope there is a way to just loop through each element in the list of dictionaries in sub-identifer.

Thanks

Comment: Don't know if it will work but try dictionary unpacking: `TestModel.objects.filter(**{'data__sub-identifier__sub_id__0': 'd2610379-abcc-4201-ad89-5f3ad3a4b1c2'})`

Comment: Thanks. But this doesn't work. I no longer get any errors, but my query set is returned as empty.

Comment: I believe you get no results because you specify index at the wrong location try `'data__sub-identifier__0__sub_id'`

Comment: Ah brilliant Abdul, that worked by moving the __0 to __0__sub_id.  Instead of specifying 0 is there a way to loop through the elements in each list?  The reason being is that my sub_id I'm looking for may not be in 0 but could be in 8, depending how many elements are in sub-identifier.

Comment: Again don't know if this works (`contains` lookup doesn't work on SQLite on which I am testing), try: `TestModel.objects.filter(**{'data__sub-identifier__contains': [{'sub_id': 'd2610379-abcc-4201-ad89-5f3ad3a4b1c2'}]})`, if it does I will post it as an answer.

Comment: Thanks Abdul, that looks like it has worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because (as you yourself likely know) hyphens `-` are not allowed in identifiers. How to solve this? Well we have the nifty feature of passing kwargs by dictionary unpacking so you can write this:

```
# 0 should be before sub_id here
queryset = TestModel.objects.filter(**{'data__sub-identifier__0__sub_id': 'd2610379-abcc-4201-ad89-5f3ad3a4b1c2'})
```

Next since you want to check for any match in the array you can use the [`contains` lookup [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#contains):

```
queryset = TestModel.objects.filter(
    **{
        'data__sub-identifier__contains': [
            {'sub_id': 'd2610379-abcc-4201-ad89-5f3ad3a4b1c2'}
        ]
    }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```py
queryset = TestModel.objects.filter(data__sub-identifier__sub_id__0='d2610379-abcc-4201-ad89-5f3ad3a4b1c2')
#                                            ^
```

to this

```py
queryset = TestModel.objects.filter(data__sub_identifier__sub_id__0='d2610379-abcc-4201-ad89-5f3ad3a4b1c2')
#                                            ^
```

And update your model to use appropriate naming convention.

Please use names without a symbols that for sure will break ORM and make name impossible to be used even in an SQL query (`-` in SQL is reserved for the substitution operator as well as in python)

Comment: Thanks madbird.  This is json data supplied to me, so I may not have total control as to a third-party using a hyphen in as dictionary key name, but certainly no fields on my model has hyphen in them.

Comment: Then I think you may update the keys in received JSON before mapping it to your models. Maybe just replacing one single key in input will be enough